# How should you handle nested functions?

Tags: function, powershell

What's the proper way to call a function in PowerShell?

Example 1:

```
Function Divide
{
    Return ($a / $b)
}

Function GetNumbers
{
    $a = Read-Host "Dividend"

    $b = Read-Host "Divisor"

    Divide
}

GetNumbers
```

Example 2:

```
Function Divide
{
    Param
    (
        [Int]$Dividend,

        [Int]$Divisor
    )

    Return ($Dividend / $Divisor)
}

Function GetNumbers
{
    $a = Read-Host "Dividend"

    $b = Read-Host "Divisor"

    Divide -Dividend $a -Divisor $b
}

GetNumbers
```

I mean, why should I use the `Param` part when I can access the parent function's variables? Or is that just bad programming?

Comment: in addition to iCodez answer: the second you want to do parameter validation (which should allways be done) your first example becomes useless. Furthermore with defined params you can use the pipeline and some more other things in your function that you could not use otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the first example is that your `Divide` function will only work if it happens to be inside the `GetNumbers` function.  If you try to call it outside of `GetNumbers`, you will raise an error because `$a` and `$b` will be undefined:

```
PS > Divide
Attempted to divide by zero.
At line:3 char:12
+     Return ($a / $b)
+            ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

This means the use case of your `Divide` function is very limited and also somewhat unintuitive.  People may call the function thinking it will work (since it is at module-level) and be surprised by the results.

---

The `Divide` function in the second example however does not have this issue.  It is independent of the `GetNumbers` function and can be used anywhere a normal function can.  This has three advantages:

1. `Divide` behaves as a module-level function should, which means there are no nasty surprises for your users.
2. The use case of `Divide` has been greatly enhanced.  You can now divide two numbers anywhere you need to.
3. Your code is more robust.  `Divide` does not need to be inside a function which just *happens* to define two variables named `$a` and `$b` which just *happen* to be numbers (see how fragile the first example is?).

---

Note too that you do not need to explicitly give the parameter names in your second example.  You could just do:

```
Divide $a $b
```

And if you dislike the size of the second `Divide` function, you could always make your `Param` statement less spread out:

```
Function Divide
{
    Param ([Int]$Dividend, [Int]$Divisor)

    Return ($Dividend / $Divisor)
}
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks for that detailed answer. Definitely cleared some things up for me.